# AutoHotKey: How to add special character bullet points with a string of letters?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am trying to add special characters (different types of Dots as seen on the last row.

[image: Special Characters in Windows Character Map]

This works but I would like to use a string of letters

```
#+d::Send {U+25CF} ; dot solid
```

I tried using this - but it does not work

```
:R*?:dot1::Send {U+25CF} ; dot solid
```

Does anyone know how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for
[AutoHotKey Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm),
also known as auto-replace hotstring.

The AutoHotKey syntax for your case will be:

```
::dot1::{U+25CF}
```

Pay special attention to the "Ending Characters" section of the documentation,
listing how these strings are to be terminated.

Comment: Thank you! It resolved the issue. 
But I am still not able to understand why the first one is working and and not the other one.

Comment: It seems to be correct by the documentation, but apparently AHK does not appreciate this combination.

Comment: Perhaps using [#Hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Hotstring.htm) will work better.